# Automatic APK signing when running ADT projects

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt

I'm used to develop and debug android apps on my phone, it's pretty faster.
When I'm ok, I export a signed APK to upload to the market.

Now I use Google Maps APIs, I must add a signature to the Manifest, this signature is associated with my key I use to sign APKs for release. So I am able to export a signed APK to test on my phone, but it's not automated and I cannot view LogCat anymore.

Can I just instruct ADT+Eclipse to auto-sign  the APK before uploading it to my attached phone?

Am I missing a point?

Comment: If you just plug your phone into your computer with a USB cable and select it as the device to load your app on when you press run it should work. It will use you debug key - not your relase key - and allow you to see the logcat

Comment: I do not want eclipse to use my debug key (not associated with Google APIs), but rather use my release key and prompt for a password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this via ADT directly. But you could use ant to build instead which supports signing (http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html).

Just set the key.store, key.alias, and key.store.password, key.alias.password properties in the ant.properties file.

You can also trigger ant builds from within eclipse and add a new ant target to install/launch the app on your device