# Keystore: delete password

Tags: java, android, keytool

I have a keystore (keytool key storage), which is used for signing .apk's from Eclipse-ADT.
Due to the extremely annoying password requests at each export, I'm trying to figure out how to avoid reentering password.

My current options are:

- by using Perl/X1::::XTEST, automate password entering (insecure)
- hack Eclipse to cache passwords (potentially insecure, explicit timeloss)
- remove keystore password, which seems to be the best possible idea

Attempt to set empty password failed:

```
>> keytool -keystore /work/X/googleplay.key -alias X -keypasswd
Enter keystore password:  
New key password for <X>: 
Password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
New key password for <X>: 
Password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
New key password for <X>: 
Password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Too many failures - try later
```

Comment: About "insecure" comments forthcoming: I think it's an "average" security level - to have an unprotected key stored inside highly protected (truecrypt, VM environment) resource; and I will keep password in plaintext (option #1) anyway, so let's just figure out how to fool keytool, ok?

Comment: *"annoying at each export"* - how frequently are you building official packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JKS keystores can't be used without a password. The best option is to pass your keystore password on the command line somehow - for example, instead of using the ADT to sign your files, trigger an `ant` build like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17413131/991432).

If you really want to have a passwordless keystore your only option is to write your own implementation of `KeyStore` (although you still have to be able to tell your signing tools to use it) - see [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) for more details.

Comment: Well, you can save / load JKS keystores without password. Using the java API, .store(<stream>, <empty char array>), and .open(<stream>, null). Of course, eclipse & other apps usually won't convert empty strings to null (so the load on their side will fail) - so you can use this mostly in yous own apps.