# Export Android signed apk automatically

Tags: android, build, apk

To export a signed apk in Eclipse I do:

> right-click on project folder -> Android Tools -> Export Signed
>   Application Package -> enter keystore password -> enter alias password
>   -> click Finish.

Is it possible to write a script that carries out these actions automatically?

I tried to use Android Studio several times, but its performance was worse than Eclipse (builds several times slower).

Comment: Actually you should start with Android Studio instead of eclipse. So please no more R&D in eclipse regards Android development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412766/automatic-apk-signing-when-running-adt-projects